# How do I get macvim tabs to display graphically?

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I've installed macvim via `brew install macvim` and turned on the "With a tab for each file" option in the preferences, but the tabs I get are VIM style tabs. Not the OS tabs you see on the macvim homepage: http://code.google.com/p/macvim/. See below for a screenshot.

Is there anything I can do to get the OS tabs?

[image: Macvim screenshot]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try do `set guioptions+=e`. This should fix your problem.

From `help guioptions`:

```
'e'     Add tab pages when indicated with 'showtabline'.
        'guitablabel' can be used to change the text in the labels.
        When 'e' is missing a non-GUI tab pages line may be used.
        The GUI tabs are only supported on some systems, currently
        GTK, Motif, Mac OS/X and MS-Windows.
```

To see the current value of your `guioptions`, do `:set guioptions?`

It's very likely that in your `.vimrc` you removed `e` from your `guioptions`. Here is my `guioptions` that works the way you wanted:  `guioptions=gtrLme`

Comment: Thats done the trick, thanks! I had indeed overwritten some of the defaults to get rid of superfluous scrollbars etc. It is now `set guioptions=aiAe`

Answer (score 2):

Other option to always show the tab bar.

Add to vimrc:

```
set showtabline=2
```

From the vim_mac mailing list archives.
 https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/vim_mac/showtab/vim_mac/zvw9MQYhnsg/jDNsqgDsHQ4J